# "Is all of" view search doesn't work with the module "Better exposed filter"

Tags: 8, views

- Drupal version :  8.2.0
- Module "Better exposed filter" version :
  8.x-3.0-alpha1

**In short :**

I created a view with an exposed filter. When I use the operator "is all of" from my exposed filter, all works. My exposed filter shows some tags in a select/option html list. I downloaded and installed the module "Better exposed filter" for display my exposed filter in checkbox instead the select/option html list. If I configure my exposed filter for it display checkboxs, then the view displays no result.

**In detail :**

I created 3 simples contents of type 'articles' :

- Recipe one (tags 'ingredients' : salt, sugar )
- Recipe two (tags 'ingredients' : super, pepper )
- Recipe three (tags 'ingredients' : pepper, salt )

I created a very simple view :

[image]

[image]

When I do a search, I get two of my articles if I select the tag "sugar" with the exposed operator "is all off" : (look the Query, **only one "INNER JOIN"**)

[image]

Tags exposed filter is an html select/option list. I want to change this style by a list of checkboxs. So, I configure the filter style with the "better exposed filter" module :

[image]

When I do that, my view works when I search with the filter exposed operator "is one of". But when I use the filter exposed operator "is all off", no result displayed !

[image]

In the new query, I noticed there are two "INNER JOIN". The second uses an id = 0, the error must be here.

My questions are :

- Do I forget something in my configuration ?
- Is a bug in the module "better exposed filter" ?
- What should I do to operate the operand "is one off" when I display it in list of checkboxs ?

Comment: I just saw this post : https://www.drupal.org/node/2651102 x) it seems its a module bug

Comment: Hmmm this link is slightly different..the proposed patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2651102-83-reroll-checkboxes-in-exposed-forms-for-8-1.patch was already in my code

Answer (score 0):

No, It's a bug with the Better Exposed Filter module. From the looks of it, something is causing a '0' value to be added as a part of the `WHERE` clause.

You can see this in action by toggling the **Allow multiple selections** filter option; when the option is off you can select a non *- Any -* value to filter the view as expected; when the option is on any selection appends '0' value to the filter.

From looking at your linked issues, they look potentially related but not the same. You should look through the [BEF module issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/better_exposed_filters) and if it's not posted yet, post it there to be reviewed.